# How to block google logo image in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, adblock

I am using Firefox 21.0 in Linux Slackware. I have Adblock Plus addon. Wanted to block this Google logo near the search panel:

[image]

I found, that this element in located in `<a class="gb_ob gb_la"`. When I delete this element in DOM panel, the image disappears. But when I added `google.co.uk##a[class="gb_la"]` to Adblock filter, it doesn't block this element.

What's wrong?

Comment: In chrome I right clicked on it and then added the image to block list and it disappear, did you tried that? Can you post a full SS of the screen too?

Comment: @avirk Unfortunately, there is no image block list in firefox. I tried to install the addon, but it didn't work. Can you look in firefox, if you have it?

Comment: @avirk "Can you post a full SS of the screen too?" I can, but won't it be too big to fit the page?

Comment: yes it seems Firefox has their own home page with that logo so adblock right click menu doesn't showing up while in chrome it is working like a charm. I'll see if i could find a way with firefox because my favorite browser is chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in [userContent.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserContent.css) file or write a new style with it using [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/stylish/) to block it:

```
@-moz-document url("about:home") {
#searchEngineLogo {
display: none !important;
}
}
```